# MySQL BinLog Statement Retrieval

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

I have seven 1G MySQL binlog files that I have to use to retrieve some "lost" information.  I only need to get certain INSERT statements from the log (ex. where the statement starts with "INSERT INTO table SET field1=").  If I just run a mysqlbinlog (even if per database and with using --short-form), I get a text file that is several hundred megabytes, which makes it almost impossible to then parse with any other program.

Is there a way to just retrieve certain sql statements from the log?  I don't need any of the ancillary information (timestamps, autoincrement #s, etc.).  I just need a list of sql statements that match a certain string.  Ideally, I would like to have a text file that just lists those sql statements, such as:

```
INSERT INTO table SET field1='a';
INSERT INTO table SET field1='tommy';
INSERT INTO table SET field1='2';
```

I could get that by running mysqlbinlog to a text file and then parsing the results based upon a string, but the text file is way too big.  It just times out any script I run and even makes it impossible to open in a text editor.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never received an answer, but I will tell you what I did to get by.
1. Ran mysqlbinlog to a textfile
2. Created a PHP script that uses fgets to read each line of the log
3. While looping through each line, the script parses it using the stristr function
4. If the line matches the string I am looking for, it logs the line to a file

It takes a while to run mysqlbinlog and the PHP script, but it no longer times out.  I originally used fread in PHP, but that reads the entire file into memory and caused the script to crash on large (1G) log files.  Now, it takes several minutes to run (I also set the max_execution_time variable to be larger), but it works like a charm.  fgets gets one line at a time, so it doesn't take up nearly as much memory.